# How to bring syncronization between client and server

Tags: c, sockets, posix

My server is sending packets to the client, but the second packet is not shown.
I don't know why this is happening if my socket is of blocking type.

```
     while(1){
             memset(buf,0,1024);
             numbytes=0;

             if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 1024, 0)) == -1) {
                  perror("recv");
                  exit(1);
                 }
             buf[numbytes] = '\0';
             printf("%s\n",buf);
             fflush(stdout);
            }
  fclose(fp);
  close(sockfd);
```

Comment: What do you mean *trying to receive twice* ? Can you please clarify your question ?

Comment: Wireshark is a handy tool which can help you out in these situations

Comment: it means while loop is iterating twice ,first time i got data which i send from server second time its only ,null but according to me it should block & wait for data to come from server side.

Comment: What is `numbytes` in the 2nd run? maybe replace `printf("%s\n",buf);` with `printf("%d %s\n", numbytes, buf);`. Besides, `memset(buf,0,1024);` is not necessary if you limit your access to `0`..`numbytes`. And there are yet other flaws...

Comment: A couple of things: 1, The loop is infinite, you never break out of it. 2, You do not check of closed connection (`numbytes == 0`). 3, The call to `recv` will return _as soon as data have been copied to the buffer_, even if it's just one byte.

Comment: the problem is because of difference in size of buffers i am using at send() at server and recv() at client.Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That could be happening because your sever is sending an empty string. So your client does not block because it received the `'\0'` character and it does not print anything because it is an empty string.

The second reason could be because your server closed the connection. In this case the value of `numbytes` is zero, and your client will not print anything because you also end up with an empty string in your buffer.

One issue with your code is that if the server sends 1024 bytes or more,`numbytes` is goign to be equal to 1024 and the expression `buf[numbytes]` will cause a segmentation fault if your buffer size is also equal to 1024. You could prevent this problem by receiving 1023 instead of 1024.

Comment: Or he could treat the data as bytes, which it is, and not a string. He could try `printf("%.*s", numbytes, buf)` or `fwrite(buf, 1, numbytes, stdout)`